# Salary renegotiate after accepting the job offer

Tags: professionalism, salary, negotiation

I have been selected as a software Engineer in a company X and I have accepted the offer letter. After few days I got selected in company Y they are paying higher than company X but company X is very good and I still want to join company X only. 
My question is can I renegotiate salary from company X by showing the offer of company Y. Is it ethical to renegotiate the salary of accepted offer? Suppose If I join company X, will the salary renegotiation create any kind of bad impression in that company?

Comment: Have you signed the offer in writing?

Comment: Actually they create my account in company website when I open my account there is an option asking accept or reject I just click accept to accept that offer. No written commitment or offer letter I have signed. On the date of joining I need to sign all those documents.

Comment: So the offer was in writing and you accepted with the click of a button. Nice. Do not go back on the offer. As there are chances the company may withdraw the offer entirely. Would you like to the company say they hired Z because he asked for a lower salary than yours after you had accepted the offer?

Comment: Yes sir I just accept like that only. Actually I don’t want to lose that offer just because of salary issue.

Comment: `I got selected in company Y they are paying higher than company X but company X is very good and I still want to join company X only` -- I don't understand this line. Are you saying that -- salries being equal -- you would *rather* work for company X? Has company Y actually made you an offer, or are you just hopeful that they will make you an offer at some point?

Comment: Your next chance to increase your salary will be the next time you get a performance review of some sort. That would be the time to arm yourself with some good reasons as to why they should pay you more.

Comment: @Brandin sir actually I am hopping a offer from company Y. The salary i will get in company Y offer is higher then what X offer me already.

Comment: @NamitKumar So then I see the situation as: you're planning to take the offer from company X, as you find the offer acceptable and the position good. But you're anticipating that another company Y may make you a more attractive offer within the next month. The question is what to do in that situation.

Comment: @Brandin Actually to be honest if I say company Y salary is making me confused although I know company X is best for me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have already clicked 'Accept' on the company's website, I would strongly discourage trying to renegotiate the salary.

HR typically uses the candidate's acceptance to initiate the rest of the joining process. If you now go back to renegotiate the salary, they will have to restart the process, which is *highly* irritating. In the extreme case, they would withdraw the offer, but more likely, they will simply refuse to increase the salary offer. Now you have gained nothing from the adventure, but created a bad impression for yourself, even before you signed the papers.

Company X agreed to offer you a certain salary based on their assessment of your skills, experience, etc. and also, based on how much they were capable of paying you. Have any of those parameters significantly changed in the past few weeks warranting them to reconsider how much they pay you? Unlikely.

Comment: How would you feel if, after you have accepted an offer, the company tred to renegotiate?

Comment: I got your point @DJClayworth sir. I was in confusion so i asked this question. Now it's clear to me. Thanks.

Comment: @NamitKumar Please stop addressing everyone as 'sir'. It is mildly annoying, and might even be perceived as being sarcastic, even though you use it to indicate respect. Addressing people by their first name (or in this case, by their display name) is "respectful" enough.

Comment: Sorry to bring up an old thread. But would it also be poor form to simply request a better salary, because you've found out your worth more, while stating that you still want to join the company?

Comment: @Griffin I don't see how that is too different from the OP's question.

Answer (score 6):

> My question is can I renegotiate salary from company X by showing the
>   offer of company Y.

You could certainly try, but that approach has risks. You are basically going back on your word. Many hiring managers (like me) wouldn't be happy that shortly after you agreed to one set of terms, you are now trying to change them.

In some situations, the hiring manager can simply withdraw the offer. You could ruin your chances of working for company X, and for working with the hiring manager ever again.

> Is it ethical to renegotiate the salary of accepted offer?

Your personal ethics are unique to you, and something you must decide for yourself. It's certainly not something I would ever do, or advise my friends and family to do. But your mileage may vary.

> Suppose If I join company X, will the salary renegotiation create any
>   kind of bad impression in that company?

Quite possibly, yes.

As I indicated, you are telling your new employer that they cannot trust you to stand behind what you say (not to mention what you signed). That's not an impression I'd want to leave with my company.

For me, trust is extremely important, as is my reputation.

Comment: sir actually i told company Y about the offer i have then they told join here i will pay higher.

Answer (score 3):

If you accepted the offer, and then a few days later they called you and said, "You know, we've decided we really can't afford to pay you that much, we have to reduce the offer by 10%", I think you'd have very bad feelings about that company, regardless of where you went from there. It works both ways. Trying to change the terms of a contract after you've signed it is at best rude and technically illegal.

Something I figured out along the way in life: When you're considering taking a new job, making a major purchase, or any other sort of "big contract", make reasonable efforts to get the best deal you can, and then once you've made your decision and signed on the dotted line, DON'T KEEP SHOPPING. Don't even look at any other offers or possibilities that may come up. Because unless you got the best possible deal in the entire world, then there's a better deal out there somewhere. And if you keep looking, sooner or later you'll find a better deal. But as it's now too late, you're already committed, the only thing that knowing about the better deal does is make you dissatisfied and unhappy with the deal you made.