# Re-negotiating after getting a second offer?

Tags: salary, job-offer, new-job, negotiation, benefits

I received an offer for new position from company A (senior engineering position), and tried to negotiate a for slightly higher salary. They accepted and gave me 4 days additional to submit final decision in writing.

Two days later, I am getting a second offer from company B (also a senior position) with which I also interview around the same time. They offering slightly larger salary than what I tried to negotiate with company A and longer vacation package.

I kind of prefer company A, but don't want to turn down a better offer from company B. Can I negotiate salary or vacation a second time with company A? Is it ethical or would I better just go with what I was able to negotiate the first time?

Comment: I am new to this forum. If you down grade my question, please explain why.

Comment: People should remember why the downvote is there, I think. They're using it improperly more and more...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Salary renegotiate after accepting the job offer](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/43135/salary-renegotiate-after-accepting-the-job-offer)

Comment: @SliderBlackrose Care to explain why this question should not be downvoted? All that it is asking for is "should I take job A or job B?". That is a decision only the OP can take based on what he considers important. I don't see how we can provide any useful answers here.

Comment: The other part of the question about whether the OP should negotiate again also cannot get any useful answers. The technically correct answer, of course, is yes, which is nothing more than a Mathematician's Answer. The implied question is how would the company respond to it, which we have no way to guess, so we can't give anything useful there either.

Comment: I am asking if it is ok and ethical to try to negotiate the second time. You don't know enough about job A or B to give me opinion.

Comment: As this site is directed at a general audience, not just long-term professionals, the question of whether this would be a proper thing to do IS valuable to someone new to the job market. "The technically correct answer is yes" MAY be generally accepted by someone who has had long hours in the trenches, but for someone new to negotiations it is a valid question that will impact them now AND in future applications. If you've come from the culture of "Here's what we pay, take it or leave it" that retail exists in, negotiations for your first corp. job is a strange and unfamiliar territory.

Comment: @SliderBlackrose Maybe I am stupid, but "Senior Engineering Position" doesn't sound like the kind of job you would expect to be offered to someone new to the workforce, nor the kind that comes with "take it or leave it". Does it sound any different to you?

Comment: The site is directed at a general audience, but that does not mean *every question* is directed at the general audience. If for every question, we wanted to create a repository of answers from the perspective of all possible industries, locations and experience levels, we could possibly do without the bazillion tags we have created for each.

Comment: @21347924720932423 Well, suit yourself. If you want answers to consider "enough information" about your jobs, then you would have to disclose it. You can make do with the answers based on "insufficient information"  instead. You asked why your question was downvoted, so I told you. It doesn't really concern me if I don't know enough about your jobs, or what job you decide to take.

Comment: Technically, you didn't answer him. You asked me. Second, yes, there are ways for a "Senior Engineering Position" applicant to be new to the hiring process. They may have had a recruiter for a first position. They may have had one job previously and this is their first experience with negotiation. I was offered my first position with just my application and a prayer. My second was handed to me. My third was re-entry into my field. When the job after that came along I was a Sr. Developer, but had yet to negotiate my own contract or have any interest in doing so.

Comment: "I really want to accept your offer, {COMPANY A}, but I was offered a better package by {COMPANY B}. Is there anything you can do to {increase compensation or other benefits}?" is both a valid and effective way to try for a second negotiation.

Comment: A few days ago someone posted here who started his first job fresh from university and stayed 20 years with the same company. That could be someone in his forties with no negotiation practice whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for ethical...that's a very broad term open to a lot of opinion.

You can always try for negotiations. Nothing prevents you, aside from them saying "no, take our offer or leave it". Until the paperwork is signed you can make any negotiations you feel are warranted, but each time will be a roll of the dice.

The fact that they gave you 4 days for final decision speaks to me like they're almost prepared for you to make some movement in negotiations, but that could be my personal view on it.

Answer (score 11):

> Can I negotiate salary or vacation a second time with company A?

You can try. You can negotiate a third time, then a fourth time, and so on.

At some point, company A will decide that you are a high-maintenance type and that they don't want to play games any more. They will either say "take it or leave it" or just say "Offer withdrawn. Go away."

Be ready with your reply when that happens.

Answer (score 1):

Opinion based answer, but this is a very opinion based question:

Is it ethical?  Asking for opinion and everyone will have one from their own view.  Mine, not really a matter of ethics.  You have not signed, you are not yet under contract, so negotiations are still open.  Yes, you agreed, but they also gave you time to consider.

Is it reasonable?  Different question, different opinion.  No, in my opinion, it is not reasonable.  Negotiate a salary you want to begin with.  If a 2nd company came in with a significantly larger offer, that is different, but you specifically stated that your first negotiation was for slightly more, and this offer is again for slightly more by your own measure, not significantly more.  So, you want to re-open off an agreed to salary for a minor bump.  IMO, no.

For a significant offer, completely ethical and even reasonable to go and say, hey, I want to come, but B just offered me a bucket of gold.  Can you at least come close?  To come back again without telling me you have another offer, would stretch in to unethical.  And for only slightly more, regardless of if you told me why you wanted to re-open or not, now you are just trying to nickel and dime me.  And if you are willing to do that while just trying to get in the door, then your are going to keep doing it, or keep looking to jump ship after you are there.  Very bad precedence in my opinion.